# Cannot run executable from Dockerfile

Tags: java, shell, docker

I have tried in various ways to run the following command:

shell form:

```
CMD java -jar ImageTester.jar -ml LAYOUT -k $APIKEY -f ../screenshots -p $PROXY -s $URL
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: java: not found
```

exec form:

```
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "ImageTester.jar", "-ml LAYOUT -k $APIKEY -f ../screenshots -p $PROXY -s $URL" ]
```

I get this error:

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
RUN node --version

RUN npm install
RUN npm i puppeteer

CMD [ "java", "-jar", "ImageTester.jar", "-ml LAYOUT -k $APIKEY -f ../screenshots -p $PROXY -s $URL" ]
```

As your can expect, this works in my local.  What am I missing?

Comment: What does your dockerfile look like? it may be as easy as putting the full path to java IE: /usr/bin/java blah blah

Comment: can you be more specific?  what do you mean by 'full path'?  Are you saying I should path java in my Dockerfile?

Comment: He means, what does your docker file look like? Is it built on Java? CentOS? It may just be a matter or changing "java" to "/usr/bin/java" in the CMD statement above.

Comment: I have updated with complete docker file.

Comment: Usually Docker files that execute Java program inherit from java docker image. Something like `FROM openjdk:8` on top of the Docker file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dockerfile should either have a base image gotten from https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/ or equivalent

or your Dockerfile needs to install java before it can call it...
Java is not part of the standard commands on a linux machine.

you are using node which does not contain java but nodejs which is JavaScript :-) not the same...

Normally though if you want a node application to call a java application in docker it is good practice to create a node image with the node application and a java image with the java application and let them talk to each other.

See for best practices this article https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: no you should use another image for that. It is bad practise to do more than one thing in a container

Comment: Hmm...two docker images for one container?  I am guess I have never done that before so I am not sure how that would work...I guess I will research it.

Comment: @MadCatm2 he means, you should limit what you do in a container. Think of it as a one purpose role, not like a vm.

Comment: Oh I see, so node commands in one container and java binaries in another container...within the same cluster, right?

Comment: Correct, try to keep things as services/microservices that is what docker is intended for.